# JDBC Mixed Case Table and Column Names

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Is it possible in Java, using JDBC, to insert into a DB2 table (or any RDBMS) where the table names and columns are mixed case? For example, I want to execute SQL such as this:

```
insert into schemaname."TableName" ("ColumnName1", "ColumnName2") VALUES ('a', 'b')
```

So I try putting that into a format such as the following, substituting single quotes for the double quotes used for table and column names shown above:

```
Integer x = jdbcTemplate.update("insert into schemaname.'TableName' "
                        + "('ColumnName1', 'ColumnName2') VALUES (?,?)",
                        new Object[] { col1, col2});
```

However, this (and any other formatting I've tried) gives me sql errors that seem to take issue with my syntax (e.g., DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `\"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes are for character literals (aka "strings"), not for identifiers. You need to use double quotes the same way you do in plain SQL. However inside a Java String, you need to escape the double quotes:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into schemaname.\"TableName\" "
                    + "(\"ColumnName1\", \"ColumnName2\") VALUES (?,?)",
                    new Object[] { col1, col2});
```

This is one of the reasons why using quoted identifiers is usually not such a good idea.

Comment: I'll be damned. It works like a charm. Thanks a million!